# Javascript. Increase or decrease float as little as possible

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision, rounding-error

In javascipt I have av floating point "a" like this:

```
var a = 5.;
```

Now I want a new number "b" that is barely larger than "a". I could do this:

```
var b = a + 1.e-10;
```

But what if "a" is a really small number?

```
var a = 5.e-20;
var b = a + 1.e-10;
```

Now "b" is many orders of magnitude larger than "a".
Also if I make the difference between "a" and "b" too small, a large "a" could cause the difference to be rounded off.

How do I make the number "b" larger than any number "a", but closer to "a" than any other number that is larger than "a", or how do I make a number "b" that is smaller than "a" but closer to "a" than any other number smaller than "a".

Edit:
Too be more specific: I'm looking for a function "makeLarger(a)" That takes a number "a" and return a number "b" where "b>a" will always evaluate to true and "c>a && c<b" will always evaluate to false for any number "c". And also a similar function "makeSmaller(a)". I want "a" to be any number, positive, negative or zero.

Comment: This looks distinctly like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is a pretty cool question. Related topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: @Adrian The X-question that I need help with is the question in the last paragraph. How to make "b" larger/smaller than "a", but closer to a than all other larger/smaller numbers. The solution I provided in the paragraph above does not work, because I don't want "b" to be many orders of magnitude larger than "a" if "a" is small. Also, if "a" is big, "b" will become equal to "a". Example: 1.e7 + 1.e-10 == 1.e7 evaluates to true, so if a is 1.e7, my approach would not work.

Comment: @Adrian I'm looking for a function "makeLarger(a)" That takes a number "a" and return a number "b" where "b>a" will always evaluate to true and "c>a && c<b" will always evaluate to false for any number "c". And also a similar function "makeSmaller(a)".

Comment: Ok, but what are you actually trying to accomplish? Or is this purely academic?

Comment: @Adrian I am making an axis-aligned box collision detection algorithm. I put references to all the right and left edges of my boxes into a list. Every time I check for collision, I sort the list on horizontal coordinates using insertion sort. If a right edge is sorted to the right of a left edge, a possible collision has happened, if a left edge is sorted to the right of a right edge, an overlap might have ended. The problem is that I want the detection to be inclusive, not exclusive. Swapping the less than operator with a less or equal operator in the insertion sort algorithm would not work.

Comment: Less than or equal should work, and would be both more readable and preform better. You might consider opening a question about that issue.

Comment: @Adrian ... My solution is to move the edges away from the senter of the collision box as little as possible to so that the detection become inclusive. The reason I use this list approach is to reduce the performance of the collision detection algorithm from O(n^2) to close to O(n) if the boxes are not moving too much.

Comment: @Adrian If I use less or equal I might have a situation with multiple right and left edges having the same horizontal coordinates "a". In this case, an insertion sort algorithm (depending on the implementation) would probably swap all these edges with all the other edges for every sorting, which would lead to multiple new collisions being detected even if none of the boxes are moving. If all right edges would be slightly larger that "a", say "b", then they would be sorted to the right once. I agree readability would suffer, but cannot think of a more readable always working solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `a` is positive, real and sufficiently far away from being a subnormal (in this case, greater than `1.0020841800044864e-292`), then the following should work:

```
var u = Number.EPSILON/2 + Number.EPSILON*Number.EPSILON;
var b = a + a*u;
```

Note that `b = a * (1+u)` *won't* work. (e.g. if `a = 0.9999999999999998`).

The basic idea is that the gap between floating point numbers is roughly proportional, but only increases in steps (it is the same for all numbers in the same [binade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binade)). So the challenge is to choose `u` small enough so that it works for the extremes in each binade.

So without loss of generality, it is sufficient to consider the numbers `a` in the interval [1.0,2.0). We need to ensure that

```
Machine.EPSILON/2 < a*u < Machine.EPSILON*3/2
```

so that the final addition will round in the correct direction (instead of back to `a` or 2 increments). It is fairly straightforward to show that the `u` defined above satisfies these properties.

To go downwards you can do

```
var c = a - a*u;
```

P.S.: Another option, though trickier to prove, is

```
var v = 1 - Machine.EPSILON/2;
var b = a / v; # upwards
var c = a * v; # downwards
```

This has the advantage of working for a greater range (any positive, non-subnormal real number).

For subnormals, you can just add/subtract `Number.MIN_VALUE`, so combining this all together you get:

```
function nextup(a) {
    var v = 1 - Number.EPSILON/2;
    if (a >= Number.MIN_VALUE / Number.EPSILON) {
        // positive normal
        return (a/v);
    } else if (a > -Number.MIN_VALUE / Number.EPSILON) {
        // subnormal or zero
        return (a+Number.MIN_VALUE);
    } else {
        // negative normal or NaN
        return (a*v);
    }
 }

 function nextdown(a) {
    var v = 1 - Number.EPSILON/2;
    if (a >= Number.MIN_VALUE / Number.EPSILON) {
        // positive normal
        return (a*v);
    } else if (a > -Number.MIN_VALUE / Number.EPSILON) {
        // subnormal or zero
        return (a-Number.MIN_VALUE);
    } else {
        // negative normal or NaN
        return (a/v);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a Big Number approach -- to store your number as a sequence of its digits:
e. g. `123... many digits here ...45` as `[1, 2, 3, .., 4, 5]`

So you can handle reeeeeally loooooong numbers and have really great precision of your floats.

There are several js modules for this, e.g. http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber

Answer (score 0):

this may be unorthodox, but you can do the following:

1. cast the float to a string, you need not be concerned with the size of the number then (within reason).
2. find the index of the decimal point.
3. retrieve a significant group of numbers from the end (tweaking required here - something like 'up to the first couple that aren't 0 led by a 9 or whatnot')
4. cast them to an int and increase by 1
5. replace the numbers in the first string with those in the second into var b
6. place the decimal (at the previous index), cast to float.

there are some fine tuning aspects to work out but that will accomplish it.

I dont feel like writing the code for the example, but that is trivial.

Comment: It may not give the desired result, though. Adding one to the least significant digit might result in a double or float with the exact same value. Just try with `0.1`, which, as a double, is exactly `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`. Turning the final `5` into a `6` will result, when parsed, in the same value again.

Comment: FWIW, turning a double (no NaN, no infinite) into a hex representation, adding one and then converting back should give the next possible value. What OP actually needs is some kind of `nextafter()` function.