# Matlab: Find next lesser floating point number

Tags: matlab, floating-point

The Matlab function `eps(x)` returns "the positive distance from abs(x) to the next larger floating-point number of the same precision as `x`." I use this to calculate the smallest floating-point number greater than `x`, via `x + eps(x)`. I would also like to obtain the largest floating point number less than `x`, but I'm unaware of a function similar to `eps` that would facilitate this. How can I find the largest floating point number less than `x`?

Comment: The Matlab documentation is vague. If by “next larger” it is referring to ordering by mathematical greater than and not “next larger in magnitude”, then the step to the next lesser value is `-eps(-x)`. That is, the next lesser value is `x - eps(-x)`. (I would be curious what `eps(x)` is when x is the greatest finite value. Does Matlab return the step size to where the next value would be if the exponent could be incremented, or does it return infinity?)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Agreed about being vague. `eps(realmax)` returns `1.995840309534720e+292`, so it looks like the former. Thanks for the comment about step size changes below. There are cases (1, for example) for which `x - eps(-x)` is not the largest floating point number less than `x`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Note that `eps(x)` is the same as `eps(-x)`, and this corresponds with the quote from the documentation in the question ("distance from `abs(x)` to...").

Comment: For positive numbers, maybe use `y = x -  eps(x)` then if `y+eps(y) >= x`, use `y`, else use `y+eps(y)`?

Comment: @chux that is exactly what my answer does.

Comment: @AnderBiguri  Your good answer does all but the last step of reporting "largest floating point number less than x".  Instead it reports the delta.  OP should be able to take it to completion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subtract `eps` in *almost all cases*.

However as you probably have realized, this does not apply when the mantisa changes, or in other words, when you want to subtract from a power of two.

A negative-side `eps` then is easy to implement, knowing that the current `eps` is smaller than the distance to the next power of two that will trigger a step change. Therefore, the `eps` of our number minus its `eps` should do the trick.

```
function out=neps(in)

out=eps(in-eps(in));
```

This seem to work fine

```
eps(2)

     4.440892098500626e-16

neps(2)

     2.220446049250313e-16
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks for adding the power of two explanation part.

Answer (score 0):

For all numbers except subnormals (i.e. those smaller than `2.225073.8585072014e-308`) you can do:

```
v = 1 - eps()/2;
b = x / v; # next larger in magnitude
c = x * v; # next smaller in magnitude
```

(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48331382/392585)).